# Why does Switch in ReactNative show toggle animation although its value prop is not changed? (iOS)

Tags: react-native, rendering

I am experiencing some behavior of a ReactNative Switch that I cannot explain. 
I have a very simple switch (see code below). It has a fixed value prop and its onValueChange-callback is only a log. As a switch is a controlled component, I thought the UI is only rerendered when the value prop changes.

Despite my assumptions the switch shows a quick animation of toggling to false and then jumps back to true. Why is that happening? Does it have to do with the iOS specific component that is used by ReactNative?

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, View } from "react-native";

export const SwitchCell = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Switch onValueChange={() => console.log("Test")} value={true} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block the event there is a prop for switch called "onChange" where as parameter you will receive the event and the new value, you can execute a check to decide if will be necessary to set the new property o if it won't change.
In case you doesn't want to change the value of switch you have to call the methods "preventDefault()"

Comment: Note, this isn't working for me on iOS in RN 69.  I've tried using `preventDefault` in onChange, onTouchStart, and onResponderStart, but I get the same behavior OP describes.